# deploying LAMP app on AWS using circleCI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, workflow, circleci

I am trying to deploy app to AWS using CircleCI.
I have gone through document and referring to https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/

I am unable to understand the use of command under AWS

```
> steps:
>   - run:
>       name: Deploy to S3 if tests pass and branch is Master
>       command: aws s3 sync jekyll/_site/docs s3://circle-production-static-site/docs/ --delete
```

I tried running a basic yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  #  build and test jobs go here
  deploy-job:
    docker:
      - image: testapp1234/lamp_new:part1
#    working_directory: /tmp/my-project
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Deploy to S3 if tests pass and branch is Master
          command: echo "Hello"
#          command: aws s3 sync jekyll/_site/docs s3://circle-production-static-site/docs/ --delete
```

I got this error in CircleCI

```
no subschema matched out of the total 2 subschemas
  required key [workflows] not found
  jobs: required key [build] not found
```

How can i use this to deploy my app to AWS instance. Can i deploy docker containers using this command?

I am unable to understand the use of workflows here.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your complete config, right now you're not using Workflows. If so, then the only job name you can use is `build`, not `deploy-job` which is what you're currently using.

You can either 1) Fix the job name or 2) Add a proper Workflows config. You can tell when you're doing so as `workflows` will be a top-level key in this CircleCI config. Workflows specific docs can be found [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/).

I hope that helps.